# Drawing a circular, minor arc given the centre point and two other points

Tags: geometry

Does anyone know how to draw a circular, minor arc given the centre point and two other points that lie on the circle?

I want to draw the pixels directly to the screen, and preferably, not have to calculate the angles.

I am using SDL and C, but may be OK studying code given that uses a different language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All points on a circle are equal distance to the centre.

Given you know two points on the circle you can calculate this distance.

Assuming you have cartesian coordinates, for every x or y value between the known points calculate the other value so that the point is equal distance to the centre and plot these points.

I think this is conceptually the easiest way, though not the most efficient.

Comment: I ended up doing similar to what you explained here, only for the up, down, left right and the four diagonal pixels from the start of the arc to the end, storing the pixels in an array as not to iterate over them twice. This gave me either a major or minor arc which I then chose by calculating the distance, in my case I wanted the shortest (minor arc).Of course this meant that I had to use an array, which I needed to use at a later time anyway. I've upped your answer, and will accept it, but I just hope that this does not deter other people from posting answers to this question for others too.